# transfer data from 1 table to another in the same database

Tags: mysql

Is this the right syntax:

```
INSERT INTO stock (Image) 
SELECT Image, 
FROM productimages 
WHERE stock.Name_of_item = productimages.number;
```

Comment: it seems ok if you take out the comma after image

Comment: yes ive tried it its saying an error in the where clause saying unknown stock.Name_of_Item. but when i check the table the name is correct.

Comment: now another error  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'of item=productimages.number' at line 4

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio's "Import Data" task (right-click on the DB name, then tasks) will do most of this for you. Run it from the database you want to copy the data into.

If the tables don't exist it will create them for you, but you'll probably have to recreate any indexes and such. If the tables do exist, it will append the new data by default but you can adjust that (edit mappings) so it will delete all existing data.

I use this all the time and it works fairly well.

```
INSERT INTO bar..tblFoobar( *fieldlist* )
SELECT *fieldlist* FROM foo..tblFoobar
```

This just moves the data. If you want to move the table definition (and other attributes such as permissions and indexes), you'll have to do something else.

Comment: sorry i am not using sql server i am using phpmyadmin

Comment: you can run this in phpmyadmin page in console

Answer (score 0):

The query logic that you are trying appears to be not correct (the query itself is buggy).

Assuming you have the correct query for the above logic and what you are trying is to insert new rows into the table `stock` by selecting a column from `productimages` table with a matching record as `stock.Name_of_item = productimages.number`

The above logic will add redundant data in to the table.

You perhaps looking to update instead of insert, something as -

```
update stock s
join productimages p on p.number = s.Name_of_item
set s.Image = p.Image
```

Comment: What error you are getting ? Also provide the table structure into the question. If the table structure is correct as you mentioned in the question and both tables are connected as `stock.Name_of_item = productimages.number` and having column `Image` on both of them the above query should work. Make sure you have `;` at the end of the query.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'of item set s.Image = p.Image' at line 2

Comment: share the query that you are using.

Comment: i am using the query that you answer

Comment: The error says `right syntax to use near 'of item` looks like you are missing `_` for the `Name_of_item`